# How can I remove everything of a string until the last comma in C#?

Tags: c#

So I need to remove everything of a string until the last comma...
(I'm reading the string from a file where I don't know how many commas there are.)
I tried using .Trim / .TrimEnd but both don't do what I'm wanting it to do.

Here is an example what it kinda looks like:
`string example = object,1,4, 6,9-6, whg,19;`

The string I'm trying to get: `object`

So the trim should ignore everthing until the last comma.

What I tried:

`string exampleTrimmed = example.TrimEnd(',');`

The output of that ► `object,1,4, 6,9-6, whg19`

`string exampleTrimmed = example.Trim(',');`

The output of that (not sure) ► `object14 69-6 whg19`

Comment: You can Split the string on ',' and drop all but the first element. Then recombine the remaining parts.

Comment: [Trim()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=netcore-3.1) does **not** work that way, but removes the given character from the start _and_ the end. not the middle. which you'd known if you'd have tried it - any reason why you didn't?

Comment: Substring and [LastIndexOf](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjK1IfYiMvrAhWQqaQKHbBVCc4QFjAAegQIBxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fdotnet%2Fapi%2Fsystem.string.lastindexof&usg=AOvVaw18YVTtX-89YscILy9ofp2w)

Comment: A regex? E.g., `\s*\w+[^,;]*` Or without `\s*` if you want to discard the spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You desired output (`"object"`) does not match your description - to get it you need to strip everything after first occurrence of `,` (including it). For example, if you guaranteed  to have `,` in your string, you can use [`String.Substring`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netcore-3.1) and [`String.IndexOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netcore-3.1):

```
var s = "object,1,4, 6,9-6, whg,19";
Console.WriteLine(s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf(','))); // prints "object"
```

If you want to get everything after last comma you can use [`String.LastIndexOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.lastindexof?view=netcore-3.1):

```
Console.WriteLine(s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf(',') + 1)); // prints "19"
```

Comment: Thanks! Yeah the question was asked kinda stupid... I ment the first method.

Comment: This fails if `s` doesn't contain a comma.

Comment: @MoB. yes. that's why answer has _"if you guaranteed to have `,`"_ in it. Implementing check `s.IndexOf(',') < 0` should not be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is 'object' why not split by ',' and then call the array at index 0 like so:

```
    string example = "object,1,4, 6,9-6, whg,19";
    string[] parsed = example.Split(',');
    Console.WriteLine(parsed[0]);
```

Output: `object`

Edit: You say 'desired string: `object`' but you also say you want to ignore everything until the last comma.

Doing the above but using this: `Console.WriteLine(parsed[parsed.Length-1]);` outputs `19`

Comment: This is somewhat inefficient as it has to scan the entire string (a file) and store all strings between the commas in an array. It's sufficient to scan the string up to the first comma.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "last" comma? And by "until"? Your example doesn't match your wording. Do you mean "the longest prefix not containing a comma"?

Then you could use
`s[..s.IndexOf(',')];`

or to be safer,
`s[..((s.IndexOf(',') is int i && i < 0) ? s.Length : i)];`